# Highlight min value of a row that belongs to a certain column header

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table like following:

[image]

I would like to highlight the cell that has the min "Base" value in each row.

`=MIN(C3:Q3)` obviously returns the min value in that range. I am not sure how to tell the `MIN` function to only consider cells that have "Base" text in the column.

In my example, for *CPU*; it would highlght `I3`, and for the *Memory*; it would highlight `C6`.

Comment: `MIN` does not need a contiguous range of cells: `=MIN(C3,F3,I3,L3,O3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to highlight them (for example with a different color), you do not need a formula at all.
Just mark your data columns `C`, `F`, `I`, `L` and `O`.

Then you click on Conditional formatting > Manage rules > New rule > Format only top or bottom ranked values.

Here you choose "Bottom" and "1" - so it will highlight the lowest value per row. Have a look at my simplified example where the lowest values in column `A` or `C` should be marked:

[image: Conditional formatting - Lowest value in row]